# Change query value in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

I have the following tables linked as in the stored procedure below.

```
A
------
ACCOUNT_DAY  
MARK_TIME  
MARKTYPE  
PLAC_ID

B
------
EMPLOYNO  
RES_ID

C
------
PLAC_ID  
RES_ID

D
------
CAUSE_ID
PLAC_ID

E
------
CAUSE_ID  
CAUSE
```

Stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[startstoptime] 
    @employno varchar(5),
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime,
    @enddate2 datetime
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @enddate = DATEADD (d, 1, CAST(@startdate AS datetime));
SET @enddate2 = DATEADD (d, 7, CAST(@startdate AS datetime));
-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT DISTINCT B.EMPLOYNO, A.ACCOUNT_DAY,
                      (SELECT DISTINCT A.MARK_TIME
                        FROM          SYSADM.MARK AS A INNER JOIN
                                               SYSADM.PLACING AS C ON     A.PLAC_ID = C.PLAC_ID INNER JOIN
                                               SYSADM.STAFF_RESOURCE AS B ON B.RES_ID = C.RES_ID INNER JOIN
                                               SYSADM.ABSENCE AS D INNER JOIN
                                               SYSADM.ABSENCE_CAUSE AS E ON D.CAUSE_ID = E.CAUSE_ID ON C.PLAC_ID = D.PLAC_ID AND B.RES_ID = D.RES_ID
                        WHERE      (A.MARKTYPE = '1') AND (B.EMPLOYNO = @employno) AND (A.ACCOUNT_DAY >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102)) AND 
                                               (A.ACCOUNT_DAY < CONVERT(DATETIME, @endDate, 102)) AND (E.EXP_DESC IS NULL)) AS start,
                      (SELECT DISTINCT A.MARK_TIME
                        FROM          SYSADM.MARK AS A INNER JOIN
                                               SYSADM.PLACING AS C ON A.PLAC_ID = C.PLAC_ID INNER JOIN
                                               SYSADM.STAFF_RESOURCE AS B ON B.RES_ID = C.RES_ID INNER JOIN
                                               SYSADM.ABSENCE AS D INNER JOIN
                                               SYSADM.ABSENCE_CAUSE AS E ON D.CAUSE_ID = E.CAUSE_ID ON C.PLAC_ID = D.PLAC_ID AND B.RES_ID = D.RES_ID
                        WHERE      (A.MARKTYPE = '2') AND (B.EMPLOYNO = @employno) AND (A.ACCOUNT_DAY >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102)) AND 
                                               (A.ACCOUNT_DAY < CONVERT(DATETIME, @endDate, 102)) AND (E.EXP_DESC IS NULL)) AS stopp
FROM         SYSADM.MARK AS A INNER JOIN
                  SYSADM.PLACING AS C ON A.PLAC_ID = C.PLAC_ID INNER JOIN
                  SYSADM.STAFF_RESOURCE AS B ON B.RES_ID = C.RES_ID INNER JOIN
                  SYSADM.ABSENCE AS D INNER JOIN
                  SYSADM.ABSENCE_CAUSE AS E ON D.CAUSE_ID = E.CAUSE_ID ON C.PLAC_ID = D.PLAC_ID AND B.RES_ID = D.RES_ID
WHERE     (E.EXP_DESC IS NULL)
GROUP BY B.EMPLOYNO, A.ACCOUNT_DAY, A.MARK_TIME, E.EXP_DESC, A.MARKTYPE
HAVING      (B.EMPLOYNO = @employno) AND (A.ACCOUNT_DAY >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102)) AND (A.ACCOUNT_DAY < CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                  @endDate2, 102))
END
```

The result is as follows:

```
EMPLOYNO    |   ACCOUNT_DAY             |   start                   |   stop  
------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------
03064       |   2015-02-05 00:00:00.000 |   2015-02-05 05:21:00.000 |   2015-02-05 14:15:00.000  
03064       |   2015-02-09 00:00:00.000 |   2015-02-05 05:21:00.000 |   2015-02-05 14:15:00.000  
03064       |   2015-02-11 00:00:00.000 |   2015-02-05 05:21:00.000 |   2015-02-05 14:15:00.000
```

The start and stop gives the wrong answer, due to that I don't understand how to get the ACCOUNT_DAY in the subquery instead of the start and stop date, without getting a result with more than one row.

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: Is all done in MS SQL 2008

Comment: Why are you passing in enddate and enddate2 and then immediately assigning them new values? Why bother casting startdate as a datetime? It is already a datetime. I would also recommend not just blindly using a letter (a,b,c,d) as aliases. Give the alias a little meaning and your queries are easier to work with.

Comment: To help with your question we need some kind of detail. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do or what is incorrect (from a results perspective) in what you posted.

Comment: I will try and improve on my coding, @SeanLange. :)
I have in table **A**, **MARK_TIME** in two posts for one **ACCOUNT_DAY** WITH MARKTYPE '1' or '2'.
Instead of the result above, I would like to have it like below.   I understand that the result above is due to the start and end date set, so the question is how to set the dates according to the field value in **ACCOUNT_DAY**?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting... :(  
`EMPLOYNO    |   ACCOUNT_DAY             |   start                   |   stop      
------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------
03064       |   2015-02-05 00:00:00.000 |   2015-02-05 05:21:00.000 |   2015-02-05 14:15:00.000  
03064       |   2015-02-09 00:00:00.000 |   2015-02-09 05:21:00.000 |   2015-02-09 14:15:00.000  
03064       |   2015-02-11 00:00:00.000 |   2015-02-11 05:21:00.000 |   2015-02-11 14:15:00.000`